# object based graph representation in python

Tags: c++, python, graph

In the Stanford Algorithms lectures, Prof Roughgarden listed the following ingredients for adjacency list:

1. Array or List of Vertices
2. Array or List of Edges
3. Each vertex in the List of Vertices points to the edges incident on it.
4. Each edge in the List of Edges points to its edgepoints.

How to go about implementing this in python especially the combination of 3 and 4? It has been challenge for me. I had done that in C++ with pointers.
I can think of one way, please let me know if you think it is right.
Number 4 can be accomplished by a list of tuples
`Edges = [(1,2),(3,2),(4,1)]` or add another element to tuple for weight value. How to make the List of Vertices point to the edges incident on it?
`Vertices = {1 : [0,2]  2: [0,1] 3: [1] 4:[3]}` Here Vertices is a dictionary and the value of each key(vertex) is the list of indices of the Edges that contain the key(Vertex). Does that seem reasonable?

Ok, I will also give the C++ implementation of it.

```
struct Node;
struct Arcs; //Forward declarations as each of them references each other
using namespace std
struct SimpleGraph  // Has all the nodes
{
   set<Node *> nodes;
   set<Arc *> arcs;
}
//Node contains node_number and the set of arcs/edges from this node.
struct Node
{  
   int node_number; 
   set<Arc *> arcs;
}
// Arc contains start and finish node and the cost associated with the Arc/Edge
struct Arc
{
  Node* start;
  Node* finish;
  double cost;
}
```

Because we use pointers in C++ a change in Arc information is reflected in the Node automatically. Lack of pointers makes it hard to do so in python. So I was trying to accomplish the best I could do.

Comment: If you've already implemented it in C++, show the code and point out what parts did not work in python.

Comment: septi, I have now added the C++ code as well for this.

Answer (score 0):

In python basically everything is an object, so lists, dicts and maps are also objects and therefore accessed via their address (just like C++ does it when you use call by reference).

Have a look at the following code example which demonstrates that:

```
list_a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list_b = ['d', 'e', 'f']

one_dict = {'entry1': list_a, 'entry2': list_b}

def add_entry(target_list, entry):
    target_list.append(entry)

print("Our example dict:")
print(one_dict)

print("Modifying 'list_a' and 'list_b'.")
list_a[1] = 'B'
list_b[2] = 'F'
print(list_a)
print(list_b)

print("Appending new entries to 'list_a' and 'list_b'")
add_entry(list_a, 'q')
add_entry(list_b, list_a)
print(list_a)
print(list_b)

print("'list_a' and 'list_b' can still being accessed via 'one_dict'.")
print(one_dict)
```

This is the output, where you can clearly see that one_dict is holding the references to those lists:

```
Our example dict:
{'entry2': ['d', 'e', 'f'], 'entry1': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
Modifying 'list_a' and 'list_b'.
['a', 'B', 'c']
['d', 'e', 'F']
Appending new entries to 'list_a' and 'list_b'
['a', 'B', 'c', 'q']
['d', 'e', 'F', ['a', 'B', 'c', 'q']]
'list_a' and 'list_b' can still being accessed via 'one_dict'.
{'entry2': ['d', 'e', 'F', ['a', 'B', 'c', 'q']], 'entry1': ['a', 'B', 'c', 'q']}
```

Thus the implementation is pretty straight forward, just like your C++ code is.

Comment: In an undirected graph with one edge I will have a dictionary like {1 : [(edge1)], 2: [(edge1)]} and edges_list = [(edge1)] where edge1 = (1,2,20) nodes 1 and 2 and the cost. But tuple is not mutable but I guess I have to ensure that when I change (edge1) weight in edges_list by replacing edge1 by edge1' I change the values in dictionary as well. They won't be pointing to the edge copies in case of tuples.

Comment: Tuples are not mutable, but lists are.